# How to enable a Wordpress plugin to contributor?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Iam new to wordpress. I have a small blog. Iam not able to use a wordpress plugin for a contributor account. How can I enable a plugin to contributor help me.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you have a plugin installed that need to be used by a contributor user. If this is the case I guess you have 3 option:

1. Dig into the plugin look and look if when they do add_menu_page (or add_submenu_page) they left an hook for the capability parameter. If that's the case, hook into that and change it to some capability that your contributor user has
2. Install this plugin https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/members/ and configure the contributor role so that he can actually see/use the plugin. Be careful, you may end up screwing your wp if you don't pay attention or break some security rules
3. Obviously: make that user admin. But that of course can't always be acceptable. It depends on your security requirements/choice